# C - How to increment first int of a file

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, fread, fseek

I have a file where i want the first `sizeof(int)` bytes to store the number of elements following in the file. I would like to increment this value whenever i add an element to the file.

The code looks like this:

```
int main() {
    int val = 3;

    FILE *file = fopen("hey", "wb");
    fwrite(&val, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    increment_val();
}

void increment_val() {
    int val;
    
    FILE *file = fopen("hey", "ab+");
    fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    val++;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&val, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    printf("%d", val);

    fclose(file);
}
```

I initialy write an int with the value 3 to the file.
I then read this value, increment it and write it back.
However when reading the value after this it still holds the original value of 3 instead of 4.

Comment: `FILE *file = fopen("hey", "r+");`

Comment: `"a+"` opens for reading and appending. When opened in `"a"` mode, all writes occur at the end of the file despite seeking. Therefore, existing data cannot be overwritten.

Comment: The regular way to do this is to make a new file with the desired content and remove the old file.

Comment: @SinanÜnür for a text file, yes. But it would be unusual to create a new database for every update.

Comment: @WeatherVane Agreed on that. I deleted my comment before your response as I had originally misunderstood what you were saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem (thanks - good puzzle for the morning as I wasn't aware of this).  But the underlying issue is that when you open for append, the writes ignore seeking.  Thus the code in `increment_val` should be:

```
FILE *file = fopen("hey", "rb+");
```

Note that you don't need the `b` really.  You might be coming from python where that is signalling binary?

Comment: how is it distinct from my comment? So where is the puzzle?

Comment: You'll need `"b"` with MS VC, as the default mode is usually `"t"` and any `0x0D` values will be cooked.

Comment: @0___________  @WeatherVane you both are wrong. in windows `"r+"` open means write pos is shifting during read. So you need `fsetpos()`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин yes, but if you are referring to our earlier comments under the question, please see [`fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170): ***When a file is opened by using the "a" access type or the "a+" access type, all write operations occur at the end of the file. The file pointer can be repositioned by using fseek or rewind, but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is performed. Therefore, existing data cannot be overwritten.***

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I was remarking here on the sentence "Note that you don't need the `b` really." In Linux, agreed. MS VC, you do need it.

Comment: i prefer open it twice with `"r+"` to backup pos

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин which is what this answer says. But with MSVC you should explicitly open in binary mode for a binary file. There are many previous questions asking about corrupted data, where the answer was "because the file was opened in text mode by default, and all the `0x0D` data values were changed by the OS on reading."

Comment: The puzzle was I started looking at it and found the answer before there were any comments, so solved it myself as well.